# Despite Force Applied, No Movement

Tags: c#, rigid-bodies, unity-game-engine

This code is for an elevator-type platform, where once the player stands on it, it 'takes' the player up by adding force onto it.

The thing is, while the force is created, the rigidbody (the player) does not move when the elevator moves. The code was written in C#, using Unity 5. In the code, the player is assigned the public 'rb', and contains a rigidbody.
The animation is a simple animation clip that moves the elevator up. Any ideas? Thank you for your time and answers in advance.

The elevator is Kinematic, the Player is not.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 /*This script activates when the player steps on the elevator, as it takes them up a floor.*/

public class ElevatorMovementScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private bool elevatorUp = false;
    public Animation anim;
    public int elevatorDelay = 5;
    public int force = 800;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }
    /*Checks if the player has stepped onto the elevator. If the player has, it waits five seconds, and then pushes the player up.*/
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && !elevatorUp) 
        {
            Invoke("AnimationPlay",elevatorDelay);
            elevatorUp = true;
        }
    }
    /*Plays the animation of the player going up. Used for the 'Invoke' method.*/
    void AnimationPlay()
    {           
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * force);
        Debug.Log (transform.up * force);
        anim.Play ("Up");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of `force`? In many cases, if a rigidbody doesn't move, it's due to the fact that the force amount is too low

Comment: If it's really a moving platform, you should probably use a kinematic rigidbody rather than applying force. It will make the platform behave like a platform.

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios - I set the force to 500, and then to 5,000,000 it had no impact.

Comment: @31eee384 - Both the platform and player have rigidbody components with 'isKinematic' set to true. The platform still moves through the player.

Comment: If iskinematic is true, then addforce will have no effect at all

Comment: @user3280790 For the "proper" elevator simulation, I think this is what you want: a platform that has rigidbody (kinematic) and collider; a trigger attached to the elevator to detect the player; the player, with a rigidbody (not kinematic) and collider. Maybe your issue is that you expect triggers to collide with objects?

Comment: @31eee384 I checked off the 'isKinematic' box on my player object, and now it reacts. It is not going up at the same speed as the elevator, but at the very least, I can say that I have something that works. Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: @user3280790 The root of the issue is that you should not be using `AddForce` for this. Instead, you should move the elevator. I don't know if Unity's animations move objects in a way that physics works: you could use `Vector3.Lerp` as a temporary (or permanent) replacement.

Comment: @31eee384 I will look into Vector3.Lerp, and figure out what I can/should do. At first glance, it looks like it will be a bit more logical to work with. I feel a bit silly actually thinking animations would have a physical property, but when I saw a tutorial use it, well, I thought it would work as well. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this script is on your elevator's game object, in which case this line:

```
rb.AddForce(transform.up * force);
```

Will try to apply a force to the elevator, not the player. You've got to keep track of the player's rigidbody or somehow get it on demand in `AnimationPlay`.

You said that

> the player is assigned the public 'rb'

But `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` will ignore this and use the rigidbody attached to the gameobject that `ElevatorMovementScript` is attached to.

Comment: I took that part out soon after I submitted the question, as I saw it changed the component to the elevator. It does not solve the problem right now, but it is a step in the right direction for me. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @user3280790 Could you please edit the question with current code and gameobject information then? (Which gameobjects have which components, which rigidbodies are kinematic, etc.)

Comment: Done. Thank you for your continued assistance.